# Cannot install or load packages on RStudio desktop

Tags: r

I tried to install the `RcppEigen` package, but an error occurred, indicating that RStudio can't open URL. I can't install other packages either in RStudio.

```
# install
install.packages("RcppEigen")

# error message
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RcppEigen’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'
```

I just updated my R version, so all the packages are manually copied to the new library. When I try to load a previously installed package, an error occurred again like this:

```
# load a package
library(StanHeaders)

# error message
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘StanHeaders’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RcppParallel', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppParallel/libs/RcppParallel.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppParallel/libs/RcppParallel.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppParallel/libs/RcppParallel.so
  Reason: tried: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file)
```

Hoping someone can help with the two problems! Thanks!

Comment: What version of R did you upgrade to? What happened when you run `install.packages("RcppEigen")` after updating R?

Comment: I've heard that it's a bad idea to simply copy the packages over.  Try only installing from `install.packages`.

Comment: Yes, very bad to simply copy the packages, because some library files are still linked to the previous R version, which can lead to some loading issues.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the secure download setting in the global option may solve the problem. Some other solutions can be found in this [link](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-install-or-load-packages-on-r/136921?u=jinghong_zeng).